# How to change the language of the UIImagepicker?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

Im facing a problem using the UIImagepicker.
If i use the camera on my iphone the language of the camera controls are in Dutch, but if i use the camera function in my app the language is English. If i choose pictures from my album in my app it is also in English. How can i change the language?

Greetz,

Dave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image picker (and all other built-in) UI elements will always be in the same language that your app is in (to avoid a mishmash of languages in one app). If you localize your app into Dutch, the image picker will be shown in Dutch, too.

Comment: Sounds easy but im having a hard time getting it to work, i tried this: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"de", @"fr", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"]; In the application didfinischlaunching but it does nothing, then if i restart the application it crashes with a blackscreen and i have to restart my phone.

Comment: Got it to work! Just had to add localization to the .xib. Thanks

Comment: Yup, just localize your app and Xcode will do the rest! Good luck.